# android - help on layout for different devices

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout with 5 items.

> TextView - fixed height
>
> TextView - fixed height
>
> TextView with many lines and scroll **********WILL SHRINK AND GROW****************
>
> CustomView - fixed height (NOT PRESENT AT THE START IN THE XML, ADDED BY CODE)
>
> LinearLayout(with items inside, fixed height)

so since there are different devices, I need the middle Textview to shrink and grow.

What is the best Layout to use and how can I do it?

Comment: Don't use fixed heights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your views are laid out vertically, you could use a LinearLayout, setting the layoutHeight of the middle view to 0dp and the layout_weight to 1.0, meaning it will grab the remaining space.

Comment: yes, the views are laid out vertically, so it worked great, thanks